# How can I dynamically fill bootstrap columns using jquery, php & smarty?

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, smarty3

I'm building a dynamic news article module. The layout of the news article must look nearly identical to a newspaper article. The article will have a max-height relative to the view port size. The article template information will be added from the CMS. The initial design will only have a single photo and text.

The challenge is to insert a single block of content into all three columns. The first two columns will always be full, the last column may or may not be. Its simple enough to dynamically generate the columns, but I cant figure out how or when to split the content.

The layout will look similar to this:

[image: Article Layout]

How can I dynamically fill bootstrap columns?

Comment: So if I understand you right, you want the left and middle text box always be full. But the right one may or may not be filled with text. What happens if there's no text in it. What do you mean with "dynamically generate the columns"? Do you want to do it with javascript or server side (with php I guess)?

Comment: @user3528269 Basically i needed any overflow content  to move from one element to another. I found the Columnizer plugin. I'm working with it now. I believe this is the answer. https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin

Comment: What have you done so far and what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The Columnizer worked perfectly!

The Columnizer jQuery Plugin will automatically layout your content in newspaper column format. You can specify either column width or a static number of columns. And, of course, it’s easy to use! https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin